# Unable to install loopback connector for IBM DB2

Tags: node.js, npm, loopbackjs, apiconnect

While I am trying to install loopback connector for IBM DB2, I am getting the below error:

```
D:\official\office works\loopback\DB2try\employee_details> npm install loopback-connector-db2

npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail o
n node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible
. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.

D:\official\office works\loopback\DB2try\employee_details>apic loopback:refresh

Updating swagger and product definitions
Error: The LoopBack application is not loaded.

WARNING: LoopBack connector "db2" is not installed as any of the following modules:

 ./connectors/db2
loopback-connector-db2

To fix, run:

    npm install loopback-connector-db2

Cannot load the LoopBack application: Cannot create data source "IBMDB2":
WARNING: LoopBack connector "db2" is not installed as any of the following modul
es:

 ./connectors/db2
loopback-connector-db2

To fix, run:

    npm install loopback-connector-db2

Please fix the problem and run `apic loopback:refresh`
```

Kindly help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you post a copy of your `server/datasources.json` file? (Sensitive values redacted, of course)

Comment: server/datasources.json : {
  "IBMDB2": {
    "host": "1xx.1x.1xx.199",
    "port": 50001,
    "database": "SAMPLE",
    "password": "xxx123",
    "name": "IBMDB2",
    "dsn": "",
    "user": "db2inst1",
    "connector": "db2"
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

How about `npm install loopback-connector-db2 --save`?

Comment: @inquisitive: Did this help solve your issue or do you still need assistance?